# Loops for process to unificate differents excel in R

Tags: r, excel, loops, import, process

I want to repeat this process with differents Excel files, I would like to make a loops for this but I dont know where I can begin.

```
# Route in excel 
path <- "mar_2016.xls"

# Unificate data for Sheet
data_mar16 = path %>% 
  excel_sheets() %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map_df(~ read_excel(path = path, sheet = .x), .id = "Sheet")

# Select columns
data_mar16 <- data_mar16%>% select("Sheet","F_H","PE_H", "NO")


# Filter values of column Sheet
data_mar16 <- filter(data_mar16, Sheet %in% c("A", "C", "B" ))


# Save the data
write_xlsx(data_mar16, "mar16.xlsx")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as there is no test data I wrote it out in a text file... so there might be a typo:

```
# Route to multiple excel files 
paths <- c("mar_2016.xls", "mar_2017.xls")
# run a loop for the length of your char vector with files
for (i in 1:length(paths)){
  # select position from vector acording to loop index
  file <- paths[i]
  # Unificate data for Sheet
  data <- excel_sheets(file) %>% 
    set_names() %>% 
    map_df(~ read_excel(path = file, sheet = .x), .id = "Sheet") %>% 
    select("Sheet","F_H","PE_H", "NO") %>% 
    filter(Sheet %in% c("A", "C", "B" ))
  # Save the data
  write_xlsx(data, file)
}
```

another option would be to convert the code to a function and then apply this via map() to the vector (or wirte it all out in the map call).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DPH When I execute the code I return this error: 

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 7920 or 1, not size 8928.
i Input `..1` is `data`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: there is a typo... one sec I will alter my answer

Comment: @RaqS I have altered it - the "data ," from inside the filter() call was fremoved... should work now